# Post Query , breaks layout if a post is deleted

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have an issue that is occurring with a custom post type, the fields are created with ACF.

I created plugin , that has a function that uses WP_query to pull 1 post and display it in a Divi Module using a shortcode.

It works fine, displays everything correctly. However if you delete the post its displaying , then reload the page, the site layout breaks in that section.

I initally thought it may have something to do with resetting the query, and tried wp_post_reset , but nothing seems to work

Note, that if the post that was deleted is restored from the trash, then all is well again .

Here is a link to the code:
https://gist.github.com/colbyalbo/8fb906f7c20a7bc2b035b2d7bcc36912

Comment: It's worth noting that this is implemented on the Front page (static page).

Answer (score 0):

Disregard.  I had a DIV imbalance somewhere in there. Rebuilt it , adding one thing at a time, and cant reproduce the error.